# jQuery looping an ajax call until finished and return the callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have to functions containing ajax requests. The first makes a request for a batch. Based on the batchId it then keep getting the batch until it returns done all while storing the cumulative results. Once the it returns done then the batchRequest should return a callback with all of the results.

I don't want to use setTimeout with this, as it has some problems with the Android WebView. It should just immediately make another getBatch check after the previous completes.

```
var batchRequest = function(request, callback) {
$.ajax({
    //some ajax request here
    success: function(data) {
    var results = [];

    getBatch(data.batch.id, function(result) {
        results.push(results.item);

        if (result.done) {
        callback(results);
        } else {
        getBatch(result.id);
        }
    });
    }
});
};

var getBatch = function(batchId, callback) {
$.ajax({
    //get using the batchId
    success: function(data) {
    callback(data);
    }
});
};
```

Originally I had the getBatch function nested inside of the batchRequest function, but I don't feel that's the best way to do it. How can I have the batchRequest loop getBatch and return everything when it's finished?

Comment: Your code right now will definately not work because `$.ajax` is asynchronous. You might be well off using a `promise`.     http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: I know the code I posted wouldn't work, but I've now added my own answer without using promises. Not sure if it's the best way of doing it, but it seems to function the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to shorten it down to something like this (untested):

```
var getBatch = function (request, callback) {
    var results = [],
        getBatchPart = function (batchId) {
            $.ajax({
                // ajax params
            }).done(function (data) {
                results.push(data.item);

                if (data.done) {
                    callback(results);
                } else {
                    getBatchPart(batchId);
                }
            });
        };

    $.ajax({
        // ajax params
    }).done(function (data) {
        getBatchPart(data.batch.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd still like to seperate out the getBatch and requestBatch logic. What would the benefits be to using `done` over calling a function recursively like I did in my answer?

Comment: Because your answer does the exact same thing as mine, but you've increased complexity by adding a third function for no additional benefit. You're still putting a second function inside the primary (to keep `callback` in scope), and only using it as a proxy to call the external function. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution to my problem that let me keep both functions. If I wrap the `getBatch` call in another function called `getNext` then it  chains the calls while appending the data to the results variable. Finally when it returns that it's done it'll send that to the callback with the comprehensive results.

```
var batchRequest = function(request, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        //some ajax request here
        success: function(data) {
            getNext(data.batch.id);
        }
    });

    var results = [];
    function getNext(batchId) {
        getBatch(batchId, function(result) {
            results.push(result.item);
            if (result.done) {
                callback(result);
            } else {
                getNext(result.id);
            }
        });
    };
};

var getBatch = function(batchId, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        //get using the batchId
        success: function(data) {
             callback(data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: that's some bad recursivity imo, why don't you keep the connection open without jquery? check out this http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming

Comment: what's bad about it? it simply downloading the batch as fast as possible, then when it's finished it's finished. there is no need to keep an open stream after the data has been retrieved.

Comment: mmmmh nm, since it's async the engine will use another stack every call. But you are just simulating a stream no?

Comment: the ajax puts in a request, the server processes the request, then the ajax retrieves the processed json data.